# Stretching vertical space to evenly fit a part of the document within minimal number of pages

Tags: spacing, music, lilypond

I typeset a book containing musical pieces using LaTeX and LilyPond (using `lilypond-book`). Each piece starts in a new page, and can be from less than a single page up to several pages long.

I want each piece to fill the required number of pages fully, so no space is left in the bottom part of the last page of the piece and the staves in all pages are evenly spaced. This can be achieved in LilyPond by setting `ragged-last-bottom` to `##f`. Here is a simple example (`music.ly`):

```
#(set-global-staff-size 32)

\paper {
  paper-width = 18.5\cm
  ragged-last-bottom = ##f
}

\header{
  tagline = ##f
}

{
  c c c c c c c c c c c c c c c c c c c c c c c c c c c c c c c c c c c
  c c c c c c c c c c c c c c c c c c c c c c c c c c c c c c c c c c c
  c c c c c c c c c c c c c c c c c c c c c c c c c c c c c c c c c c c
  c c c c c c c c c c c c c c c c c c c c c c c c c c c c c c c c c c c
  c c c c c c c c c c c c c c c c c c c c c c c c c c c c c c c c c c c
}
```

This will produce this output:

Page 1/2:
[image: Page 1/2 of good output]

Page 2/2:
[image: Page 2/2 of good output]

Now, when I try to use this in LaTeX, it doesn’t work, since `lilypond-book` splits the LilyPond output into `.eps` files each containing a single line and these files are included one after another by the generated `.tex` file.

So, this LaTeX file produces an output which does not fill the pages fully with evenly spaced staves (as you can easily see by looking on the last page):

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{geometry}

\begin{document}

hello world

\lilypondfile{music.ly}

\end{document}
```

Page 1/3:
[image: Page 1/3 of bad output]

Page 2/3:
[image: Page 2/3 of bad output]

Page 3/3:
[image: Page 3/3 of bad output]

So my question is simple: how do I make LaTeX behave like LilyPond does with `ragged-last-bottom` set to `##f`?

Thank you very much! ☺

Comment: Is my question not clear or nobody knows how to do this?

Comment: Perhaps the latter. LaTeX shipouts a page immediately after it typesets enough materials. So it is hard (not impossible) to decide how many lines should be on the first page without knowing how many lines in total. By the way, 41 is prime... what do you expect in this case? (13,14,14) or (14,14,13) or (14,13,14)?

Comment: @Symbol1: So if no one will come with a LaTeX solution I will have no option but to embed PDF files produced by LilyPond ([tag:pdfpages]), which is not an elegant solution, to say the least.

Comment: @Symbol1: As for number of lines/staves which is not dividable by the number of pages: the grouping should be according to the slight differences in height (the spaces between lines should be as similar as possible in size). If all lines are of the same height, I guess the simplest rule will be to make the first pages more dense: 10 lines on 3 pages should be 4-3-3, 11 lines on 3 pages should be 4-4-3.

Comment: Given that you are basically inputting the generated file, I'm not clear what kind of solution you are looking for. That is, I take it you want to not be editing that file, but then it is hard to see what can be done since the contents is not even available to manipulate as part of the document.

Comment: @cfr: What I want is to automatically manage the **space** between the included `.eps` files (each containing a single line/staff, not the whole page) so that the output will be evenly spread across the pages. It could have been anything else: spreading tables, `.png` images, equations, you name it so that they will fill the pages evenly.

Comment: So you do want to edit the generated file? In that case, an example of that would be helpful! Or are you trying to influence the way lilypond generates the file? That is, is this a LaTeX question or a lilypond question? (Obviously, both. But which are you wanting to directly deal with?)

Comment: @cfr: As mentioned above `lilypond-book` processes the file generated by LilyPond; you can read about it here: http://www.lilypond.org/doc/v2.19/Documentation/usage/latex http://www.lilypond.org/doc/v2.19/Documentation/usage/lilypond_002dbook . It is a LaTeX question, since what I want to control is the space between these embedded `.eps` files (whose content or origin LaTeX is agnostic of: they are just ‘images’ in a sense).

Comment: As I’ve said, it could be a question about spacing between any other kind of boxed material (tables, images, equations, etc.); I’m not interested in LilyPond in particular in this respect.

Comment: But your example does not reflect that structure, does it? It is just one thing: input this other file with (here unspecified) content.

Comment: Actually it does, as this code is to be processed using `lilypond-book`, which replaces `\lilypondfile{music.ly}` with a series of `\includegraphics` commands. `lilypond-book` allows one to specify what will be included between these `\includegraphics`s by defining `\betweenLilyPondSystem`, as one can see in the documentation (http://www.lilypond.org/doc/v2.19/Documentation/usage/latex). The content of `music.ly` is not unspecified; it is given in the question.

Comment: OK, but you are limiting the group of people potentially able to answer your question to those who: (1) have `lilypond` installed or are willing to install it, (2) know how to use it or are prepared to learn. If you present the question in a way which does not depend on those things, you will increase the chances of getting helpful answers. Of course, it is your question. But if you want to maximise the chances of getting help, you need to think about your question from the point of view of people who are not you. Note that, as others explained, the problem is hard: you must attract an expert.

Comment: Thanks for the advice and the willingness to help! I will edit the question tomorrow, rephrasing it in a more general manner.

Comment: In the generated file what is between the includegraphics inclusions? If there is a blank line it would seem `\setlength\parskip{\fill}` is all you need?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: I can put anything I want between the `\includegraphics` inclusions (for example, to get a `\par` between them, I declare `\newcommand{\betweenLilyPondSystem}[1]{\par}`). If I understand correctly, using `\setlength\parskip{\fill}` will yield `n-1` dense pages and the last page can be very sparse (depending on the input and the page dimensions).

Answer (score 11):

Interesting problem! Ultimately, lots of figuring out and legwork, but the solution ends up being very simple.

Thanks for introducing me to lillypond—cool stuff.

I'm still a bit confused because I've only been using it for about 5 minutes, but here's what I found.

You make this file, I called mine lillypond.ly:

```
#(set-global-staff-size 32)

\paper {
  paper-width = 18.5\cm
  ragged-last-bottom = ##f
}

\header{
  tagline = ##f
}

{
  c c c c c c c c c c c c c c c c c c c c c c c c c c c c c c c c c c c
  c c c c c c c c c c c c c c c c c c c c c c c c c c c c c c c c c c c
  c c c c c c c c c c c c c c c c c c c c c c c c c c c c c c c c c c c
  c c c c c c c c c c c c c c c c c c c c c c c c c c c c c c c c c c c
  c c c c c c c c c c c c c c c c c c c c c c c c c c c c c c c c c c c
}
```

I took this straight from the your question.

Also straight from the your question is this file, I called mine lillypondtex.lytex (The .lytex extension is important and was difficult to figure out.)

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{geometry}

\begin{document}

hello world

\lilypondfile{lillypond1.ly}

\end{document}
```

This file gets compiled with the command `Applications/LilyPond.app/Contents/Resources/bin/lilypond-book --output=out --pdf lillypondtex.lytex` at least, if you're on a mac and too lazy to follow the installation instructions. On a normal installation I think this command would be just `lilypond-book --output=out --pdf lillypondtex.lytex`.

That command generates a new directory, called `out`, which contains a directory called `5a` (important later) and the files:

```
lillypondtex.dep
lillypondtex.tex
snippet-map--9077002354240704700.ly
snippet-names--9077002354240704700.ly
```

Now we're getting somewhere, finally an extension I know and love!

Running `pdflatex` on `lillypondtex.tex` gives the same output you saw and didn't like.

The `lillypondtex.tex` file contains this:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{geometry}

\usepackage{graphics}
\begin{document}

hello world

{%
\parindent 0pt
\noindent
\ifx\preLilyPondExample \undefined
\else
  \expandafter\preLilyPondExample
\fi
\def\lilypondbook{}%
\input{5a/lily-66b633c5-systems.tex}
\ifx\postLilyPondExample \undefined
\else
  \expandafter\postLilyPondExample
\fi
}

\end{document}
```

Still a little obfuscated, but the line `\input{5a/lily-66b633c5-systems.tex}` is the key.

Now, going into the `5a` directory, we have the file called `lily-66b633c5-systems.tex` which is finally the layout code for the document.

```
\includegraphics{5a/lily-66b633c5-1}%
\ifx\betweenLilyPondSystem \undefined
  \linebreak
\else
  \expandafter\betweenLilyPondSystem{1}%
\fi
\includegraphics{5a/lily-66b633c5-2}%
\ifx\betweenLilyPondSystem \undefined
  \linebreak
\else
  \expandafter\betweenLilyPondSystem{2}%
\fi
\includegraphics{5a/lily-66b633c5-3}%
\ifx\betweenLilyPondSystem \undefined
  \linebreak
\else
  \expandafter\betweenLilyPondSystem{3}%
\fi
\includegraphics{5a/lily-66b633c5-4}%
\ifx\betweenLilyPondSystem \undefined
  \linebreak
\else
  \expandafter\betweenLilyPondSystem{4}%
\fi
\includegraphics{5a/lily-66b633c5-5}%
\ifx\betweenLilyPondSystem \undefined
  \linebreak
\else
  \expandafter\betweenLilyPondSystem{5}%
\fi
\includegraphics{5a/lily-66b633c5-6}%
\ifx\betweenLilyPondSystem \undefined
  \linebreak
\else
  \expandafter\betweenLilyPondSystem{6}%
\fi
\includegraphics{5a/lily-66b633c5-7}%
\ifx\betweenLilyPondSystem \undefined
  \linebreak
\else
  \expandafter\betweenLilyPondSystem{7}%
\fi
\includegraphics{5a/lily-66b633c5-8}%
\ifx\betweenLilyPondSystem \undefined
  \linebreak
\else
  \expandafter\betweenLilyPondSystem{8}%
\fi
\includegraphics{5a/lily-66b633c5-9}%
\ifx\betweenLilyPondSystem \undefined
  \linebreak
\else
  \expandafter\betweenLilyPondSystem{9}%
\fi
\includegraphics{5a/lily-66b633c5-10}%
\ifx\betweenLilyPondSystem \undefined
  \linebreak
\else
  \expandafter\betweenLilyPondSystem{10}%
\fi
\includegraphics{5a/lily-66b633c5-11}%
\ifx\betweenLilyPondSystem \undefined
  \linebreak
\else
  \expandafter\betweenLilyPondSystem{11}%
\fi
\includegraphics{5a/lily-66b633c5-12}%
\ifx\betweenLilyPondSystem \undefined
  \linebreak
\else
  \expandafter\betweenLilyPondSystem{12}%
\fi
\includegraphics{5a/lily-66b633c5-13}%
\ifx\betweenLilyPondSystem \undefined
  \linebreak
\else
  \expandafter\betweenLilyPondSystem{13}%
\fi
\includegraphics{5a/lily-66b633c5-14}%
% eof
```

These `\linebreak` commands are the problem, that's why LaTeX is treating the music as a single paragraph and not spreading it out evenly.

**Any changes made here will effect the output of `lillypond.tex`. From here, I'm sure there are more experienced people here who can tweak this further than I can.**

---

## However, a couple simple solutions:

Simply find-replacing all cases of `\linebreak` with `\par` will allow `\flushbottom` to be used as expected in `lillypond.tex`. output:

[image]

This fixes spacing between all the lines and text. Making each line of music a paragraph is the solution I would choose if I were writing a book using this, as it would work with `\flushbottom` and flow around text well. Also, at this point, David Carlisle's asnwer of pasting `\setlength\parskip{\fill}` into the `lillypond.tex` file will work as he intended.

Another option is to replace each `\linebreak` with `\vfill`, which gets us closer to OP's desired outcome by filling the full last page.

From here it's just a matter of shrinking the margins to make them similar to lillypond's output. A margin of .75" top and bottom gives this output:

[image]

Even spacing, pages fully filled, I believe this is what you're asking for.

Final `lillypond.tex` file:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[margin=.75in]{geometry}

\usepackage{graphics}
\begin{document}
\flushbottom

\centering
hello world

{%
\parindent 0pt
\noindent
\ifx\preLilyPondExample \undefined
\else
  \expandafter\preLilyPondExample
\fi
\def\lilypondbook{}%
\input{5a/lily-66b633c5-systems.tex}
\ifx\postLilyPondExample \undefined
\else
  \expandafter\postLilyPondExample
\fi
}

\end{document}
```

Another option I just thought of is to use `\pagebreaks` in conjunction with `\vfill` to explicitly declare how many lines to show per page.

---

## If you want default `Article` margins:

How to space out lines so they're evenly distributed with `article` class default margins: Use `\par` between the lines of music and then define `\parskip` like this:

```
\setlength\parskip{26pt plus 36pt minus 0pt}
```

This tells LaTeX that each line must have 26pt in between, and it's allowed to satisfy `\flushbottom` by stretching each line by 36pt but not allowed to compress the lines closer together.

Here's the result:

[image]

LaTeX breaks it up into two pages of five lines and one page of four lines.

Here's the code I used to make it:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[]{geometry}

\usepackage{graphics}
\begin{document}
\flushbottom

hello world

{%
\parindent 0pt
\noindent
\setlength\parskip{26pt plus 36pt minus 0pt}
\ifx\preLilyPondExample \undefined
\else
  \expandafter\preLilyPondExample
\fi
\def\lilypondbook{}%
\input{5a/lily-66b633c5-systems.tex}
\ifx\postLilyPondExample \undefined
\else
  \expandafter\postLilyPondExample
\fi
}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the effort and looking into it! You can change the `\linebreak` into `\par` by defining `\betweenLilyPondSystem`, like this: `\newcommand{\betweenLilyPondSystem}[1]{\par}`. However, even with `\setlength\parskip{\fill}` and `\flushbottom` I get the first `n-1` pages dense and the last page possible very sparse (depending on the input and the page dimensions).

Comment: In the given example the last page has only two lines: one on the top and one on the bottom. This should not be so, it should have 4 or 5 lines, just as the first two pages.

Comment: @JúdaRonén That's an issue of margins, I showed how to adjust the margins to get output like the `lillypond` output. If you use the default `{article}` margins, you obviously won't get the same number of lines per page. I'll update my answer showing how to space them out though.

Comment: @JúdaRonén I've updated the answer to include an example showing normal `article` margins.

Comment: Perhaps I misunderstand you, but if we shorten the musical piece the last page will have a lesser number of lines, won’t it?

Comment: Yes, so then you could make the typographical decision whether you want fewer lines on the other pages or not. I'm confused by your question, what are you looking for? Typographically, you should know how many lines per page you want for legibility's sake, and how much stretch you want or don't want when there aren't that many lines on a page. I've showed you how to do that, I'm not sure what you're looking for now. There's no magic "prettifier" feature that I know of, LaTeX is a great tool but like all great tools it does what you want instead of what it wants.

Comment: But that’s exactly what I want LaTeX to do automatically, to fill *up* (that is, top to bottom) all pages spreading lines more or less uniformly. This is what LilyPond does with `ragged-last-bottom = ##f`. Anyway, I’ve awarded your answer with the bounty since I’m very grateful for it and the lengths you went to help me, but I cannot accept it though, as it does not fully answer my question. Thanks! ☺

Comment: Thanks! I've looked some more, all I can think of is writing explicit rules using `\if` switches (which I don't know how to use...) to implement logic, and then explicitly declaring how many lines of music will be in the section, with something like `\linesinpiece{24}` that gets passed back to a class somewhere... Sorry! Good luck with your book!